# Using restify on website which requires user login authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, restify

I have been using restify as REST API server. I am also using angularjs with the front-end html, css, js files being hosted on an Apache webserver. I would like to add user login authentication to this webapp.

Users need to login to gain access to the web app. If they are not authenticated, they will be redirected to a default URL at `www.webroot.com/login.html`.

After googling, I discover that most of the node.js code examples are based on Express. In my context, would using Express be a better choice? Express seems more integrated as it also act as a webserver. My preference is to use restify since my existing app is written in restify. Can restify still be used to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this module `restify-ensure-login`. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-ensure-login

> This middleware ensures that a user is logged in. If a request is
>   received that is unauthenticated, the request will be redirected to a
>   login page. The URL will be saved in the session, so the user can be
>   conveniently returned to the page that was originally requested.

From your question, you seem to have the wrong notion that restify is unable to act as a static webserver unlike Express. The fact is, restify is able to serve as a static webserver and what's more, this can be done with only a few lines of code. Here you go;

```
server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': 'static', //html, css files placed in static folder
    'default': 'index.html'
}));
```